# Magento 2: Image Processing Settings - GD2 V/s ImageMagick

Tags: magento2, image, performance

Go to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Image Processing Settings**

[image]

By default, it's PHP GD2.

1. We need to use ImageMagick or GD2?
2. Is there more benefit of ImageMagick over GD2?
3. What is recommended?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7690

Answer (score 5):

I recommended ImageMagick as far as image quality goes. It seems to produce considerably sharper/higher-quality images than GD2 (at the expense of larger filesize.)

ImageMagick is also not bound by PHP's memory limit.