# Magento2-Product PNG Image is resizing as Transparent due to which it's showing as blank on Product/Category/Product Admin Grid Page

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.4, image-resizing

**PNG product image is not showing** on the front end.

When i checked for the **reason then found this format is resizing but always resized a blank image** due to which it's not showing(as we know that to show the product images only thumbnail image used) on category and product pages.

Even it's not showing on admin product grid section.

While JPG format is working fine.

**LibPNG version is "   1.5.13" and server OS is Centos**.

We're **using Magento 2.2.4 version**.

**Note:-** During R&D someone suggest to downgrade/upgrade libPNG version but due to some server end problem it's not upgrading/downgrading.

while on fresh M2.2.4 setup it's working fine on same server.

I'm using porto theme.also tried the same by changing the theme from the backend but no luck.

[image]

It's urgent so please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Check Image using browser inspect element and if image showing correcting in src url, then check and try to remove porto css from head which is loading for admin then check it.

Comment: thanks for the reply.already checked and it's also displaying blank/transparent.

Comment: I am having same problem, I am using magento 2.2.5 EE edition and .png image does not showing in admin product grid and as well as at product details page in front-end sometimes. It just shows blank transparent image when open the url of image. Does anyone have clue what's going on behind the scene? Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158137)

Answer (score 0):

For me there **was some problem in "pub/media/catalog/product"** directory,actually we were imported product with images from other site(dot net) during that may be some problem raised.

So i have replaced this directory with fresh one and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the issue described here along with its solution: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17450

You have to change the image adapter to ImageMagick. More info here: [Magento 2: Image Processing Settings - GD2 V/s ImageMagick](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174108/magento-2-image-processing-settings-gd2-v-s-imagemagick)

Note that in order to change it you have to be in developer mode. Also note that you have to have ImageMagick installed on the server